# How to make changes to a different git repository from a jenkins job

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I have two git repositories:

- myapp
- gitinitdeploy

Myapp contains my regular application code. The build on this repository produces and pushes a docker image. The docker image will be tagged with the git commit hash.

gitinitdeploy contains k8s descriptor to be applied by a gitinit pod.

At the end of the myapp deploy build I want to update the k8s descriptor in gitinitdeploy so it points to the new docker image. (This will then trigger the redployment in k8s).

I already have suitable ssh secret for a a github used in my jenkins secrets.
How do I use this secret in the myapp build to access the gitinitdeploy repository?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to think about doing it the same way you would do it if you were doing it manually on your local machine.

Your job will need to clone the gitinitdeploy repo. Replace the text in your k8s descriptor (sed is probably the easiest way) and then commit and push it.

Depending on your Jenkins setup you can checkout to a subfolder in the workspace to avoid any overlap with your primary repo.

Comment: My question is mainly how to set up git access so the jenkins script can clone and push. I found this in the mean time:
environment {
MYJENKINS_SSH_KEY = credentials('my-personal-token')
GIT_SSH_COMMAND = "ssh -i ${MYJENKINS_SSH_KEY}"
}
I am getting an error though when doing the git clone:
11:26:05  Warning: Identity file **** not accessible: No such file or directory.
11:26:05  Host key verification failed.
11:26:05  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.